# Why is DB2 treating an empty string as null?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Using DB2 10.5 on Windows x64

```
UPDATE dbo.datasource_databases
SET HOST = ''
WHERE ID = 1

Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column "TBSPACEID=2, TABLEID=6, COLNO=1" is not allowed.. SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, DRIVER=3.67.28
```

HOST is a VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL

Is this expected behavior? If so, how should I work around this and if not, what could be causing this?

Edit: Along the same lines, `SELECT ID, HOST from dbo.datasource_databases WHERE HOST != ''` returns 0 rows, where checking for `HOST != 'some gibberish'` will return rows. To me this makes even less sense than the above behavior (shouldn't it just treat it as `HOST NOT NULL`?).

Comment: IIRC (and I've not gone to check the [DB2 10.5 manuals](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.kc.doc/welcome.html)), it is "because it does" (and probably the SQL standard allows this), and the workaround is to store a space `' '` instead of an empty string `''`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That could only happen if Oracle compatibility or at least Oracle's VARCHAR2 data type compatibility is enabled for the database, as [described here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052880.html?lang=en). Normally DB2, as prescribed by the ANSI SQL standard, treats empty strings as strings of zero length, not NULLs.

Comment: This turned out to be it. Apparently setting `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=20` or `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA` causes all VARCHAR fields to be treated as VARCHAR2.

I ended up having to do some fiddling with the registry since `db2set` wasn't properly updating the setting everywhere, but once I cleared everything, restarted the database manager, and recreated the database, it finally started working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's the price you pay to be "compatible with Oracle database".